# Maximum file size in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm hoping to develop an IDE which can handle large Verilog files (up to 5GB) using Eclipse's Theia. Since Theia is built off of VSCode and assuming they can handle the same file sizes, what is the largest file size that VSCode can handle, and how can you change its configuration to increase the maximum file size?

I tried using the command: `code --max-memory [file-size]` , however it didn't work.

In order to create a dummy 1GB text file for testing, use the following command:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=1gb-file bs=1000000000 count=1`

Thanks for the help!

**Clarification, simpler question: How do I display files of size ~1GB on VSCode?**

Comment: Do you want to render the file as text or using your own visualization?

Comment: The visualisation is already there, it is based off the same visualisation VSCode uses. To clarify the question, how can I display files of size 1GB or more on VSCode?